# Writing gzipped output file without extra disk space with pipe

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, gzip

I have the following implemented functionality for reading gzipped files without disk usage.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> // for mkstemp() and std::system()
#include <memory>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <unistd.h> // for ::close() and unlink()

void foo (std::ifstream& in, std::string& fileName)
{
    char tmpName[] = "/tmp/tmp.XXXXXX";
    const int fileDescriptor = mkstemp(tmpName);

    if (fileDescriptor >= 0)
    {
        std::string tmpFileName (tmpName);
        ::close(fileDescriptor);
        unlink(tmpFileName.c_str());
        std::string cmd= "mkfifo " + tmpFileName;
        int systemReturnVal = std::system(cmd.c_str());

        cmd = "gunzip -c " + fileName + " > " + tmpFileName + "&";
        systemReturnVal = std::system(cmd.c_str());
        assert(systemReturnVal);

        fileName = tmpFileName;
    }
    in.open(fileName, std::ios::in); 
}
```

And this works fine. I'm trying to implement support for writing compressed output with the same technique, i.e. write in pipe and output to gzip.

```
// same includes
void foo (std::ofstream& out, std::string& fileName)  
{
    char tmpName[] = "/tmp/tmp.XXXXXX";
    const int fileDescriptor = mkstemp(tmpName);

    if (fileDescriptor >= 0)
    {
        std::string tmpFileName (tmpName);
        ::close(fileDescriptor);
        unlink(tmpFileName.c_str());
        std::string cmd= "mkfifo " + tmpFileName;
        int systemReturnVal = std::system(cmd.c_str());

        cmd = "gzip -c " + tmpFileName + " > " + fileName + "&";      
        systemReturnVal = std::system(cmd.c_str());
        assert(systemReturnVal);

        fileName = tmpFileName;
    }
    out.open(fileName, std::ios::out); 
}
```

The problem is the segmentation fault which occurs at this line: `out.open(fileName, std::ios::out);`

Please help me to understand what I'am doing wrong and how to properly implement the second `foo()`.

**EDIT**

Note, that before segfault also outputs the following message.
`gzip: /tmp/tmp.qoc18X: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: What are you passing as `out`?

Comment: Your snippet does not compile for various reasons. Please fix them and then copy and paste a fully contained snippet (doesn't have to contain a main, but must have all relevant includes).

Comment: @immibis, a default constructed ofstream object passing as `out`

Comment: @NarekAt Your posted code still does not compile. Do not try to fix it. Copy and paste it from an editor where you successfully compiled it.